# Obtener datos de una vista sin input con laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Buen dia,
Estoy mandando una variable a una vista con un formulario:

```
return view('formulario.create', compact('form'));
```

al momento de guardar lo que se lleno en el formulario requiero guardar
el valor mismo valor de 'form', normalmente obtendria el valor de la vista y  el controlador
vista:

```
<input id="id" type="text" value="{{$form->id)}}">
```

obteniendo el valor en el controlador:

```
$form = $request->input('id');
```

pero ahora necesito obtener el valor de form->id sin mostrarlo en la vista, sin input.

¿Abra alguna forma de obtener ese valor desde el controlador para guardarlo?

Comment: Tu pregunta no es del todo clara, puedes explicar mejor?

Comment: cambia `type="text"` por `type="hidden"`

Comment: Prácticamente quiero mandar un dato de un metodo del controlador a otro metodo del mismo controlador